# Process.Start c# process crashing

Tags: c#, asp.net, process

Im trying to execute .exe file from asp.net mvc 3 like this `Process.Start(@"C:\HLDS\hlds.exe");` but hlds.exe opens crashing immadiatly.

It Does not have problem when im opening it myself(double click)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Sounds like the process requires a specific user context. What user is your ASP.NET application running as?

Comment: Or perhaps your hlds.exe need to be executed inside its working directory.

Comment: User have administration rights. what does it me executed inside working directory? I opening it with double click and its works . Form asp.net its opening but in few seconds windows showing error 'has stopped working'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try with this code?
It's possible that the program needs some data/file present in its working directory.
In this case you could specify the WorkingDirectory using the ProcessStartInfo class

```
ProcessStartInfo pi = new ProcessStartInfo("hlds.exe");
pi.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\HLDS";
Precess.Start(pi);
```